# How can I arrange these three UILabels using auto layout programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I have a `UIView` that has three `UILabels` on it.  I have a `title`, `subtitle`, and `subtitleDescription`, all `UILabel` properties.  I want my title on the top left, the subtitle below the title no gap, and the subtitleDescription to go to the right of the subtitle no gap, aligning the baseline with the subtitle baseline.  I want elipses if the view, or views in the case of the subtitle/subtitleDescription.  I Would like to use auto layout programmatically.

Similar to this:

```
  _________________________________
 |[title]                         | 
 |[subtitle][subtitleDescription] |
 |________________________________|
```

I want the labels to go to the upper left hand side rather than centering.  In my code right now, it is all centered and all the labels are on top of each other.

I just call `sizeToFit` on all the `UILabel`'s, other than that I don't adjust the frame at all.  Of course this code is after I alloc and init the labels and set the text.  Here is my code:

```
 - (void)setup
 {
[self.title sizeToFit];
[self.subtitle sizeToFit];
[self.subtitleDescription sizeToFit];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[title]-(>=0)-|"
                                                            options:kNilOptions
                                                           metrics:nil
                                                             views:@{ @"title" : self.title }]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subtitle]-5-[subdesc]-(>=0)-|"
                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:@{ @"subtitle" : self.subtitle,
                                                                        @"subdesc"  : self.subtitleDescription }]];

// compR > compR
[self setContentCompressionResistancePriority:900 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[self setContentCompressionResistancePriority:500 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[title]-5-[subtitle]|"
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:@{ @"title"    : self.title,
                                                                        @"subtitle" : self.subtitle }]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.subtitleDescription
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self.subtitle
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:0]];
 }
```

Thank you!!!

Here is a screen shot of the view:

[image]

***Update***

As jrturton pointed out to me, it looks like all my constraints are being broken from the constraints exceptions.  I am looking to figure out why they are broken.  The message given is "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints".

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the layout that this code is producing?

Comment: When I use this class in another place, I set the frame to be (0, 0, 300, 300), and this view is centered within the 300 x and y.

Comment: It looks like those labels would be too big to fit into that view anyway, are you seeing constraint exceptions in the log?

Comment: Honestly, if you must do it from code, i'd create a puppet project, drag&drop the same layout using interface builder and from the running app, i'd NSLog all the constraints to the conseole and set the constraints on the production app based on that.

Comment: Actually, why should you do it with code? Use IB and add constraints so the bottom labels have specific distance from the top one and specific distance to each other.

Comment: @ZoltanVaradi that's a terrible suggestion! This layout is achievable with three VFL statements.

Comment: @jrturton I don't believe the labels are too big because I just set the width and height to be 2,000 and it did the same thing.  I just checked and I am getting constraint exceptions and it looks like all of my constraints are getting broken.  "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" it says.  I just need to figure out why they are broken.  Thanks!

Comment: Add the log to the question if you like - but first check the first line of my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure your labels are autolayout-enabled by setting `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`.

You don't need any of the `sizeToFit` calls. At the point of adding constraints, they are meaningless. The labels will use their intrinsic size at the point of layout.

To prevent centring, simply don't pin to both sides of the superview. So instead of this:

```
"|[title]-(>=0)-|"
```

Do this:

```
"|[title]"
```

Or indeed this:

```
"|[title]|"
```

And set left alignment on the label.

For multiple labels in a line, you'd want this:

```
"|[subtitle]-5-[subdesc]|"
```

Passing `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline` in the options. You can OR (`|`) the options together if required. Again, you don't need the inequality spacing. A left aligned label will take as much space as it needs to. You may want to set compression resistance / hugging priorities on the two labels so you have rules on which one is truncated if there isn't enough room to display both values.

You're setting content compression resistance on the view itself, this is meaningless if the view itself is not also subject to auto layout. You're also setting it twice to two different values, I'm not sure what you are hoping to achieve with that.

Your current vertical constraints will, if the superview has a fixed size, cause one or other of the labels to be stretched to fill the remaining size, which will centre the text vertically, that's what labels do when they are too tall.

You can overcome this by not pinning to the bottom:

```
"V:[title]-5-[subtitle]"
```

I've written extensively about VFL and auto layout [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/), with links to other autolayout-related articles.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was making a lot of small mistakes.  Thanks for the help.  I had my translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints set to YES.  And I was adjusting that on this views superview.  Plus a few smaller details.